# Optimizing MariaDB for 5-10K small databases

Tags: performance, mariadb

Running a SaaS based on MariaDB LTS (1:10.1.44-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) with nearly 5000 databases (1 per tenant). Average per tenant: 8MB of data (on disk) with ~50 tables. CPU/Mem load is negligible. It's been running fine for a couple years, with some 5-20 tenants added per day.

However. When the nr of dbs grows to about 5150, the MariaDB server process crashes. So far I haven't been able to distill a useful log message, unfortunately. Furthermore, it takes about 10 minutes for MariaDB to start up, which is quite long when I want to experiment with new settings.

What settings would you recommend to reduce the risk of crashing, and speed up starting time?

Some more characteristics:

- [SHOW GLOBAL STATUS](https://gist.github.com/gwillem/da1dcf35e49010fc8380823e6cda438d#file-show-global-status-txt)
- [SHOW VARIABLES](https://gist.github.com/gwillem/da1dcf35e49010fc8380823e6cda438d#file-show-variables-txt)
- Server has 2CPU and 8GB ram, of which 25% is available during peak times.
- Load per CPU core never exceeds 0.20 during peak times
- Connections are short lived, I expect that there are never more than 20 concurrent db connections.
- All tables are InnoDB
- Schema may differ per database (but are probably identical for 98% of tenants)
- I use stock configuration, except for:

```
innodb_file_per_table
open_files_limit        = 65536
log_warnings            = 3
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1G
```

FWIW, I'm willing to upgrade to a newer version of MariaDB, but given the risk of new uncertainties, I'd rather make an informed decision than take a leap of faith.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I think that you should be looking more at your OS capabilities than those of the MySQL server! Many of the MySQL limits are theoretical in any case and if you're even approaching them, you could be in trouble. From [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/database-count-limit.html), there is no limit on the number of servers, but it also says that `The underlying file system may have a limit on the number of directories.`!

Comment: Thanks, however, am running ext4 which either has a subdir limit of 64K (or even unlimited) and am currently just below 5K. 

Also, open files at OS level is set to 1M for the `mysqld` process, but actual open files is ~2K (`ls /proc/$(pgrep mysqld)/fd | wc -l`). Furthermore, the MariaDB data partition has some 4.5M inodes available (at 11% usage). 

Any other limits that come to mind?

Comment: `ls /proc/$(pgrep mysqld)/fd | wc -l` seems to be a rather long-winded way of replacing `lsof`- no: :-)

Comment: Up for 5 days, "Max_used_connections": 23 -- this confirms your "never more than 20 concurrent".

Comment: I can't imagine that any server would croak on 5150 directories in a single parent directory.  Slow, yes; croak, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Observations:**

- Version: 10.1.44-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
- 8 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 4d 23:42:13
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

Unless you have a lot of other apps on the server, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be increased, perhaps to 5G.

There is pressure on the "table_open_cache", which is currently set to 2000; double that.

Increase `table_definition_cache` from 400 to 1000

`innodb_log_file_size` is rather small.  However, making it larger is a pain for your old version, so I don't recommend at the moment.

Are you using ARIA?

A lot of complex queries.  See this for investigating them:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

You have a bunch of stored procedures?  And some of them do PREPARE and EXECUTE?  Some of them seem to fail to CLOSE (DEALLOCATE) them.  This may lead to excessive memory usage.  (I don't know if this could be causing the crash, but you should clean them up.)  And consider `subquery_cache=off` (see `optimizer_switch`)

**Details and other observations:**

`( Opened_tables ) = 2,098,690 / 430933 = 4.9 /sec` -- Frequency of opening Tables
-- increase table_open_cache (now 2000)

`( Opened_table_definitions ) = 1,397,838 / 430933 = 3.2 /sec` -- Frequency of opening .frm files
-- Increase table_definition_cache (now 400) and/or table_open_cache (now 2000).

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,024`
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( innodb_io_capacity_max / innodb_io_capacity ) = 2,000 / 200 = 10` -- Capacity: max/plain
-- Recommend 2. Max should be about equal to the IOPs your I/O subsystem can handle. (If the drive type is unknown 2000/200 may be a reasonable pair.)

`( Innodb_pages_written / Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests ) = 1,753,906 / 7374538 = 23.8%` -- Write requests that had to hit disk
-- Check innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 1073741824)

`( Innodb_os_log_written / (Uptime / 3600) / innodb_log_files_in_group / innodb_log_file_size ) = 737,214,976 / (430933 / 3600) / 2 / 48M = 0.0612` -- Ratio
-- (see minutes)

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 430,933 / 60 * 48M / 737214976 = 490` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, this can be changed dynamically; be sure to also change my.cnf.
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size (now 50331648). (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( innodb_flush_method ) = innodb_flush_method =` -- How InnoDB should ask the OS to write blocks. Suggest O_DIRECT or O_ALL_DIRECT (Percona) to avoid double buffering. (At least for Unix.) See chrischandler for caveat about O_ALL_DIRECT

`( default_tmp_storage_engine ) = default_tmp_storage_engine =`

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor.

`( Innodb_deadlocks ) = 2 / 430933 = 0.017 /HR` -- Deadlocks
-- SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; to see the latest pair of queries that deadlocked.

`( sync_binlog ) = 0` -- Use 1 for added security, at some cost of I/O =1 may lead to lots of "query end"; =0 may lead to "binlog at impossible position" and lose transactions in a crash, but is faster.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( innodb_buffer_pool_populate ) = OFF = 0` -- NUMA control

`( log_warnings ) = log_warnings = 3`

`( (Com_show_create_table + Com_show_fields) / Questions ) = (622768 + 622768) / 21607187 = 5.8%` -- Naughty framework -- spending a lot of effort rediscovering the schema.
-- Complain to the 3rd party vendor.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( Qcache_lowmem_prunes/Qcache_inserts ) = 2,656,624/4159715 = 63.9%` -- Removal Ratio (frequency of needing to prune due to not enough memory)

`( (query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) / Qcache_queries_in_cache / query_alloc_block_size ) = (16M - 4531192) / 4235 / 16384 = 0.176` -- query_alloc_block_size vs formula
-- Adjust query_alloc_block_size (now 16384)

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables ) = 1,309,758 / 430933 = 3 /sec` -- Frequency of creating *disk* "temp" tables as part of complex SELECTs
-- increase tmp_table_size (now 16777216) and max_heap_table_size (now 16777216).
Check the rules for temp tables on when MEMORY is used instead of MyISAM. Perhaps minor schema or query changes can avoid MyISAM.
Better indexes and reformulation of queries are more likely to help.

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Questions ) = 1,309,758 / 21607187 = 6.1%` -- Pct of queries that needed on-disk tmp table.
-- Better indexes / No blobs / etc.

`( Created_tmp_disk_tables / Created_tmp_tables ) = 1,309,758 / 2706252 = 48.4%` -- Percent of temp tables that spilled to disk
-- Maybe increase tmp_table_size (now 16777216) and max_heap_table_size (now 16777216); improve indexes; avoid blobs, etc.

`( (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) / Com_commit ) = (27132 + 306536 + 20780 + 1296) / 372094 = 0.956` -- Statements per Commit (assuming all InnoDB)
-- Low: Might help to group queries together in transactions; High: long transactions strain various things.

`( Select_scan ) = 3,511,698 / 430933 = 8.1 /sec` -- full table scans
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 3,511,698 / 14426841 = 24.3%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( Com_stmt_prepare - Com_stmt_close ) = 12,457,121 - 12445287 = 11,834` -- How many prepared statements have not been closed.
-- CLOSE prepared statements

`( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = STATEMENT` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED.
-- ROW is preferred by 5.7 (10.3)

`( slow_query_log ) = slow_query_log = OFF` -- Whether to log slow queries. (5.1.12)

`( long_query_time ) = 10` -- Cutoff (Seconds) for defining a "slow" query.
-- Suggest 2

`( Subquery_cache_hit / ( Subquery_cache_hit + Subquery_cache_miss ) ) = 356,216 / ( 356216 + 10183006 ) = 3.4%` -- Subquery cache hit rate

`( log_slow_slave_statements ) = log_slow_slave_statements = OFF` -- (5.6.11, 5.7.1) By default, replicated statements won't show up in the slowlog; this causes them to show.
-- It can be helpful in the slowlog to see writes that could be interfering with Slave reads.

**Abnormally small:**

```
Com_show_status = 0.0084 /HR
Handler_write = 0.11 /sec
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Acl_database_grants = 4,656
Acl_users = 4,658
Aria_pagecache_reads = 2.9 /sec
Com_create_db = 0.9 /HR
Com_drop_db = 0.14 /HR
Com_drop_user = 0.14 /HR
Com_grant = 0.9 /HR
Com_release_savepoint = 0.067 /HR
Com_rollback_to_savepoint = 1.9 /HR
Com_savepoint = 0.067 /HR
Com_show_create_table = 1.4 /sec
Com_show_fields = 1.4 /sec
Com_stmt_close = 29 /sec
Com_stmt_prepare = 29 /sec
Com_unlock_tables = 0.06 /sec
Feature_fulltext = 0.067 /sec
Feature_subquery = 34 /sec
Feature_timezone = 0.054 /sec
Handler_savepoint = 0.067 /HR
Handler_savepoint_rollback = 1.9 /HR
Innodb_pages0_read = 223,449
Tc_log_page_size = 4,096
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
innodb_default_row_format = compact
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
```

Comment: I did not spot this before, but `Com_show_create_table` is very high -- more than 1/second.  This could be stressing the file and table caches, thereby leading to the crash you are seeing.  What package is delivered with the SaaS?

Answer (score 1):

Your output for `GLOBAL_STATUS` is showing:

```
opened_tables 2098690
```

The definition for this status is defined as:

> Number of tables the server has opened...

<sup>***Reference:*** [Opened_tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-status-variables/#opened_tables) (MariaDB documentation)</sup>

Your configuration for `innodb_file_per_table` is set to:

```
innodb_file_per_table   ON
```

And MariaDB defines this setting to be:

> If set to ON, then new InnoDB tables are created with their own InnoDB file-per-table tablespaces. If set to OFF, then new tables are created in the InnoDB system tablespace instead. Page compression is only available with file-per-table tablespaces. Note that this value is also used when a table is re-created with an ALTER TABLE which requires a table copy.

<sup>***Reference:*** [innodb_file_per_table](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_file_per_table) (MariaDB documentation)</sup>

So basically, you have 2'098'690 open files on your Ubuntu Server, but your settings for `innodb_open_files` is set to 2000:

```
innodb_open_files   2000
```

Now there could be an issue that Ubunutu is hitting a limit or your MariaDB is in some race condition opening and closing the database/table files.

The 2 million + open files is a counter and there is a recommendation that if your counter keeps on increasing that:

> If the number of opened tables is increasing rapidly, you should look at increasing the `table_open_cache` value. Try to find a value that sees a slow, or possibly even no, increase in the number of opened tables.

<sup>***Reference:*** [Optimizing table_open_cache](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/optimizing-table_open_cache/) (MariaDB documentation)</sup>

Additionally you might want to have a look at your Ubunutu instance and see what limits are set for system-wide resources:

```
 bash#> ulimit -a
```

This will return a list of currently set limits. You might have to increase these limits to achieve a stable MariaDB environment. The one setting being:

```
-n   The maximum number of open file descriptors.
```

<sup>***Reference:*** [ulimit](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/optimizing-table_open_cache/) (SS64.com)</sup>

You can set this setting according to this Q&A:

[How to increase max open files limit on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049058/how-to-increase-max-open-files-limit-on-ubuntu-18-04) (Ask Ubuntu)

Comment: Thank you! Perhaps I should even disable `innodb_file_per_table` ?

Comment: That is probably something you should try in a development environment and a question which I currently couldn't answer with either yes, or no.